# Missing statement in the below MYSQL query

Tags: sql, databases

I have 3 tables with columns likes-

```
Customers(customer_id,  first_name, last_name,  age country)
Orders(order_id item,   amount, customer_id)
Shippings(shipping_id,  status, customer)
```

and I want to get the result - "All those customer who has to spend over $250 and their products isn't delivered"

```
SELECT Customers.first_name, Customers.last_name,
   Orders.amount, Shippings.status
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
    INNER JOIN Shippings
        ON (Orders.customer_id = Shippings.customer)
        WHERE Shippings.status <> "Delivered"
```

Now, where should I use the WHERE statement, and how to get the desired output?
WHERE Statement-

```
        WHERE Orders.amount > 250
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked-

```
SELECT Customers.first_name, Customers.last_name,
Orders.amount, Shippings.status
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON (Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id)

    INNER JOIN Shippings
        ON (Orders.customer_id = Shippings.customer)
        WHERE Shippings.status <> "Delivered"
        AND Orders.amount > 250
```